# two floating div inside a container

Tags: html, css, containers

I try to define two div side by side. The left is div content, the right is div sidebar. These two divs are inside the container div. I tried several different ways, but none of them works. Here is my code for css:

```
#container {
   width:1000px;
   position: relative;
}



#content {
    width:700px;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 3px solid midnightblue;
    padding: 80px 10px 0px 10px;
    float:left;
}

#sidebar{
    border-top: 3px solid midnightblue;
    background-color:#E0E0E0;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 250px;
    float:left;
}
```

The code for html looks like:

```
 <div id="container">

<div id="content">
    <p> This is my blog website. </p>
</div>

<div id="sidebar">
   <p>This is the sidebar. </p>
</div> 

</div>
```

I also tried change "float:left" to "float:right" in the sidebar, and I also added: "display:table;" in the container. But it didn't work either. The sidebar is alway below the content region, it's not show in the rightside of the content div.

In the most outside, there is a wrapper class.  If I removed wrapper class and the container, then it will work. But I need the wrapper class. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `box-sizing: border-box`. [Know more about box-sizing](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

Just add below code in CSS.

```
* { 
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
  box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u6wn617g/)**

Comment: I also just found box-sizing:border-box will make the padding inside the width. But I don't know it depends on the browser as you mentioned here. Thanks!

Comment: I have written cross browser CSS. For more info http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing

Answer (score 2):

The issue pertains to the `div` padding. Reduce the width of the content div: `width:680px;` and it will display properly as shown here:

http://jsfiddle.net/k8ggmctq/

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that the total width is bigger then the container's width.
Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/kez5c71m/
I have change the padding of the #sidebar from 20 to 10

```
#container {
   width:1000px;
   position: relative;
}



    #content {
        width:700px;
        background-color: white;
        border-top: 3px solid midnightblue;
        padding: 80px 10px 0px 10px;
        float:left;
    }

    #sidebar{
        border-top: 3px solid midnightblue;
        background-color:#E0E0E0;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 250px;
        float:left;
    }
```

Comment: I was thinkig the padding is part of the div, the sum of size 700px and 250px is less than the 1000px. So the padding is not included in the width. Ah, thank you! It took me a whole night to debug this.....

Answer (score 0):

As per your CSS

```
 #container width = 1000px

 #content width   =  720px (700px + 10px + 10px left and right padding ) 

 #sidebar width   =  290px (250px + 20px + 20px left and right padding )

    Total width   =  1010px (since the total width exceeds your #container width, the #sidebar was not able to position itself properly as per css applied)
```

[checkout the working code here (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/vasanthanvas/ocbcwzw5/)

Answer (score 0):

Set your width and height of the container div and adjust your both content and sidebar div width respectively. 
Check out the below fiddle link it will work,

```
#container {
   width:450px;
    height:400px;
   position: relative;
   border: 3px solid midnightblue;
}



#content {
    width:200px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 3px solid midnightblue;
    padding: 80px 10px 0px 10px;
    float:left;
}

#sidebar{
    border: 3px solid midnightblue;
    background-color:#E0E0E0;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w5dmzoqj/